# Native Swift Upload to S3 help - Using URLSession S3 Multi Part form fields, for large files (without loading Data to ram?)

Tags: swift, amazon-s3, multipartform-data, urlsession

**TL/DR:**

I have a pre-signed post URL and fields for S3, generated from `boto3` using `generate_presigned_post`  and I want to upload some large files, in the hundreds / gigs of size to S3

A curl command like so is able to upload successfully to my bucket:

```
curl -X POST \
  # the copy/pasted fields
  -F key='filename.mp4' -F AWSAccessKeyId='AKIA...EWS3' -F policy='eyJle...dfQ==' -F signature='RcU9...XLw=' \
  # the file to upload
  -F file=@filename.mp4 \
  # the URL
  https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/
```

I am trying to get URLSession to natively mirror the above CURL invocation in any sane way. I'd prefer not to add a heavy dependency, so I was trying to roll my own. Alas, I seem blocked.

---

**Longer with Code:**

I've tried 2 methods, one using `URLSession.upload(for: fromFile:)` which internally using an UploadTask and `URLSession.data(for:)` - the latter which requires manually setting the httpBody to have data from my file.

I have a helper method to convert a name/value and boundary to a form field:

```
private func convertFormField(named name: String, value: String, using boundary: String) -> String
    {
        var fieldString = "--\(boundary)\r\n"
        fieldString += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(name)\"\r\n"
        fieldString += "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"
        fieldString += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n"
        fieldString += "\r\n"
        fieldString += "\(value)\r\n"

        return fieldString
    }
```

Which is invoked for the fields, `key`, `AWSAccessKeyId`, `policy`, `signature`, and I am relying on the `URLSession.upload(for:fromFile:)` to set the appropriate HTTP body data and chunk it for the file at the URL I specified, and am assuming its compatible with a `multipart/form-data` POST method?

```
 func upload(fileUrl:URL, toS3:S3Payload) async throws -> Bool
    {
        print("Uploading", fileUrl, toS3)
        
        guard let url = URL(string: toS3.url) else {
            return false
        }
        
        let attributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: fileUrl.path() )
        
        let fileSize = attributes[.size] as? NSNumber
        
        var request = URLRequest(url:url)
        let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"

        var httpBody = Data()

        for (k,v) in toS3.fields
        {
            let string = convertFormField(named: k, value: v, using: boundary)
            print("Field", string)
            let data = string.data(using: .utf8)
            guard let data = data else { continue }
            httpBody.append(data)
        }
                
        let totalHTTPBodyBytes = httpBody.count
        
        request.httpBody = httpBody
                
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.timeoutInterval = 30
        request.setValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue(String( totalHTTPBodyBytes + ( fileSize?.intValue ?? 0 ) ), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("100-continue", forHTTPHeaderField: "Expect")

        print("All Header Fields", request.allHTTPHeaderFields)

        // We have to use a separate URL session, since we dont want to pass our auth token for our internal API, etc
        let (data, response ) = try await self.s3URLSession.upload(for: request, fromFile: fileUrl )
          
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
              httpResponse.statusCode == 204 else {
                return false
        }

        
        return true
    }
```

The above call appears to time out on the CLIENT side, which makes no sense to me.

```
2023-06-19 15:14:08.615747-0400 Ozu[41759:3883308] Task <3ADB06DD-6F17-4F2A-AABB-233A13A387B3>.<1> finished with error [-1001] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000035952f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalUploadTask <3ADB06DD-6F17-4F2A-AABB-233A13A387B3>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalUploadTask <3ADB06DD-6F17-4F2A-AABB-233A13A387B3>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000035952f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalUploadTask <3ADB06DD-6F17-4F2A-AABB-233A13A387B3>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalUploadTask <3ADB06DD-6F17-4F2A-AABB-233A13A387B3>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}
2023-06-19 15:14:08.633225-0400 Ozu[41759:3883606] [tcp] tcp_input [C5.1.1.1:3] flags=[R.] seq=4101766915, ack=1634103508, win=251 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=4101766884, snd_una=1634103477
```

Some questions:

- Im assuming the time out is because the server is waiting multi part chunks I am not sending?
- Does the call to self.s3URLSession.upload(for: request, fromFile: fileUrl ) actually add a multipart file  appropriately to the rest of the body I am uploading?
- If it doesn't work with multi part uploads, how do I provided a large file as data to my httpBody, without loading it entirely into memory?

​

Any pointers seriously appreciated!

**Update**:

I was able to get this working thought it is suboptimal. Using `URLSession.data(for:)` works, but it requires loading the entire file into memory, which is dumb.

Is there really no way to use `URLSession.upload(for:fromFile:)` without loading your file into memory?

Comment: I was able to get upload working, by NOT using `URLSession.upload(for: fromFile:)` and properly implementing `URLSession.data(for:)` - however, when specifying I want a memory mapped Data from my file URL, it still loads it into ram. Is there no way to do large file upload without using lots of memory? 

This seems ridiculous!